# Criteria to check for subfield and subdomain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I've been doing many problems that go like here's a field verify this is a subfield or here's a domain, verify this is a subdomain.  However its often very tricky for me to see it and write clear proofs.  Is there is a list of criteria you can recommend that I can use to prove subfield and subdomain.

For instance, to check for subfield S given field F we need to show 
0 is in S, ab is in S and a-b is in S.

Are there criteria like these that I can use to check for subfield or subdomain?

Comment: You need to check also that the multiplicative unit is in $S$, and that the reciprocal of every nonzero element of $S$ is in $S$. Think of $\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb Q$ as a counterexample.

Comment: This is for subdomain or subfield?

Comment: For instance, how would you show that Z[i]={a+bi|a,b are integers} is a subdomain of complex numbers? based on the criteria you've given?

Comment: My comment was for a field; to show $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a subdomain of $\mathbb C$, you have to show it’s closed under multiplication and subtraction; and that the multiplicative unity of $\mathbb C$ is in $\mathbb Z[i]$. And that’s all.